# Loading pre-trained BERT model error - Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5'] found

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I think my problem here is due to transformer version mismatch... but I would like some help with this...

Previously I used the huggingface library to perform [language model fine tuning](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/contrib/legacy/run_language_modeling.py). This takes a corpus, an existing BERT model, and fine tune that model using this corpus. My command was

```
python run_language_modelling.py --output_dir=lm_finetune --model_type=bert --model_name_or_path=bert-base-uncased --do_train --train_data_file=thread0_wdc20.txt --do_eval --eval_data_file=wiki.test.raw --mlm --save_total_limit=1 --save_steps=2 --line_by_line --num_train_epochs=2
```

I fine-tuned the models successfully, and this created a folder that contained the following files:

```
checkpoint-183236  config.json  eval_results_lm.txt  lm_finetune  pytorch_model.bin  special_tokens_map.json  tokenizer_config.json  training_args.bin  vocab.txt
```

And I also successfully loaded this fine-tuned language model for downstream tasks.

**The problem is that I don't remember the versions of the libraries I used to do all these - pytorch, transformers, tensorflow...**

Recently, I am experimenting something that required me to re-install these libraries. Their versions are now:

```
tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0
transformers 3.0.2
pytorch 1.4.0
torchtext 0.5.0
```

And when I use this environment to reload those previously fine-tuned language models, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/li1zz/.conda/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/li1zz/.conda/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/li1zz/wop_matching/src/exp/run_bert_standard.py", line 313, in <module>
    bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert_model)
  File "/home/li1zz/.conda/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 437, in from_pretrained
    [WEIGHTS_NAME, TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME], pretrained_model_name_or_path
OSError: Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5'] found in directory /home/li1zz/bert/lm_finetune_proddesc/lm_finetune_part00 or `from_pt` set to False
```

Obviously, the file that is missing now is

```
tf_model.h5
```

I don't understand how I had this error - the fine-tuned models worked for sure before. And the only thing I can think of is the version mismatch. I.e., I fine-tuned those models using a version of the libraries that are incompatible with the ones I am now using, as one file is missing.

Can anyone provide some insights to this? Am I using wrong versions of the libraries? How can I fix this without re-doing all the language model finetuning using this new environment again?

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered that the solution should be adding 'from_pt=True' in the line that loads the model:

```
        bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert_model, from_pt=True)
```

This is actually hinted in the error message. And it should be an added feature because I clearly remember that my previous code was working and it did not have this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The files you have mentioned above indicate that you have trained a PyTorch model (`pytorch_model.bin`), but in your own answer you try to load a TensorFlow model with:

```py
bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert_model, from_pt=True)
```

As you have already figured out, you can create a TensorFlow model from a PyTorch state_dict by setting [from_pt=True](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.TFPreTrainedModel.from_pretrained). But in case it does not matter for you if you use PyTorch or TensorFlow, you could initialize a PyTorch model right away with:

```py
bert_model = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(bert_model)
```

I have not tried it, but I assume that this will be faster. The [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.TFPreTrainedModel.from_pretrained) also mentions that it is faster to convert the PyTorch state_dict with one of the provided [conversion scripts](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2.py) and loading the model afterward as using `from_pt=True`.